# R Xgboost: How to compile xgboost with GPU support on windows 10

Tags: r, machine-learning, installation, rstudio, xgboost

I followed the instructions provided in this link: [How to install xgboost package in python (windows platform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749735/how-to-install-xgboost-package-in-python-windows-platform/34958723#34958723)
and 
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#installing-r-package-with-gpu-support

My setup: Windows 10 Home x64. Installed Visual 2015, Rtools (make sure the PATH has following two items. PATH: c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin), Cmake and Git Bash.

I setup R to run in CMD and executed git bash as administrator.

**Step 1** Clone xgboost source

```
$ git clone https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
```

the above package is installed in the path: *C:\Users\Username*

**Step 2** Install xgboost

```
    cd xgboost
git submodule init
git submodule update
cd R-package
R CMD INSTALL .
```

Then the package installed successfully in *C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\library*.

**Step 3** Installing R package with GPU support

```
    mkdir build
    cd build
   cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DR_LIB=ON -DLIBR_EXECUTABLE="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/bin/x64/R.exe"
```

Then I installed the build using the following command

```
cmake --build . --target install --config Release
```

After this, the libraries are updated in *C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\library* with GPU support. Run RStudio as administrator to access the library.

Source: [Fail to install R XGBoost with GPU support on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109247/fail-to-install-r-xgboost-with-gpu-support-on-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: Have you tried following the official documentation at https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#installing-r-package-with-gpu-support?

Comment: Yes! I have tried the same. But after this step _cmake --build . --target install --config Release_ I am not sure what to do.

Comment: "When --target xgboost is used, an R package dll would be built under build/Release. The --target install, in addition, assembles the package files with this dll under build/R-package, and runs R CMD INSTALL." According to this you are done.

Comment: I am facing an issue with _cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DR_LIB=ON_. getting an error

Comment: And what's the error message?

Comment: I used _ cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DUSE_CUDA=ON_ and the execution was successful. But how can i verify is confusing

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: The above procedure worked for me