# R Xgboost: How to compile xgboost with GPU support on windows 10; can't find Visual Studio

Tags: r, visual-studio, cmake, xgboost

Edit:  Solved following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668676/cmake-visual-studio-15-2017-could-not-find-any-instance-of-visual-studio) .
Original Question:  I would like to install xgboost for RStudio into the GPU on Windows 10.
I have attempted to follow the instructions [here](https://medium.com/@karthikdulam/installing-xgboost-gpu-for-r-on-windows-10-7927a65c0ca8), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307360/r-xgboost-how-to-compile-xgboost-with-gpu-support-on-windows-10), and [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#installing-r-package-with-gpu-support); however my knowledge of Linux is not enough to understand why it isn't working.

This is my current command and error:

```
billp@DESKTOP-63F9UDC MINGW64 ~/xgboost/R-package (master)
$ cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DR_LIB=ON -DR_VERSION=3.18.0 -DLIBR_HOME="C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2"
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 16 2019

  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/billp/xgboost/R-package/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

This is my version of Visual Studio:
[image]

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Did you try running the `cmake` command from within the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt?

Comment: I ran the command in Git Bash.  This is my attempt in Visual Studio: C:\Users\billp\source\repos>cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DR_LIB=ON -DR_VERSION=3.18.0 -DLIBR_HOME="C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2"
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/billp/source" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: You will have to run the command from the **same** directory from which you ran it originally. You will also want to *delete* the CMakeCache.txt file in-between attempts.

Comment: I navigated to the same directory and received the same error after running "del cMakeCache.txt"

Comment: Solved following here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668676/cmake-visual-studio-15-2017-could-not-find-any-instance-of-visual-studio] by modifying Visual Studio for "Desktop Development with C++".  Now I have a new error which I might open in a new question.